# I can't set the video in iframe. How to do it?

Tags: html, css, video, iframe, embed

I am embedding a video in a wordpress site using iframe. But the video is not shown completely on my page. Only left part of the video is visible. Remaining part is getting cut.

The code I am using is :

```
<P ALIGN=left><iframe src="http://www.abc.com/embed/B5EECA7CE46B5A09" height="460" width="800" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginwidth="10"></iframe></P>
```

The actual code I got from the site is

```
<iframe src="http://www.abc.com/embed/B5EECA7CE46B5A09" width="600" height="360" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

So I tried to set the alignment left, set different values for marginwidth but nothing worked. What I should do in this situation?

Comment: Almost similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811740/emedded-video-controls-width?rq=1  but no one answered there.

Comment: can you make [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

By default, WordPress doesn't allow you to add some html tags (`iframes`, `style`, `script`...) inside posts or comments. You'll have to install a plugin (like this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-iframe-loader/) in order to have iframe in wordpress.

If your blog is hosted in wordpress.com then I'm sorry, AFAIK there is no way to install plugins there.